# How to define multiple overloads for a function with only optional params?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this function with overloads and optional params:

```
public void fn(int a = 0)
{...}

public void fn(string a = "0")
{...}
```

these function do same work when no params pass to them ( call fn() ), but I can not call this function with no param passed to it because of this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties ...

Comment: Man this looks like a puzzle of languages and it's very unclear.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Believe me, you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create method with empty parameter:

```
public void fn(int a)
{

}
public void fn(string a)
{

}

public void fn()
{
    //Your code goes here
}
```

That error will only happen if you don't pass any parameters to `fn()`, it's obvious, because compiler will not know what to call in that point. So your optional parameters makes no sense.

Comment: While this is true (will compile and work) - leaving parameters optional in other overloads makes not much sense after adding `fn()` overload.

Comment: @Evk yeap, I've just copied them, and forgot to remove optional parameters.